# How to insert Dictionary into Set in swift3?

Tags: swift, dictionary, set, nsdictionary

I have simple Dictionary which is defined like :

```
let dic = ["key" : "value"]
```

I want to add 'dic' into this map:

```
var map = Set<NSDictionary>()
//    var map = Set<Dictionary<String,String>>()

_ = map.insert(dic as NSDictionary)
```

I don't want to use 'dic as NSDictionary'.

But I have no idea that how can I perform this action I searched a lot on internet but nothing helps me.

Comment: `let dic:NSDictionary = ["key" : "value"]` Try this?

Comment: Just curious, why do you need a set of dictionaries in the first place? What's the use case?

Comment: What's your definition of two of those simple dictionaries being equal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regardless of what is the purpose of filling a set of dictionaries, note that the declared `dic` type is *not* `NSDictionary`, instead it is a -Swift- dictionary of strings keys and strings values (`[String : String]`).

Therefore, you would declare the set as:

```
let dic = ["key" : "value"]
var map = Set<Dictionary<String, String>>()

_ = map.insert(dic as NSDictionary)
```

**BUT** there is a problem here! you would get:

> Type 'Dictionary' does not conform to protocol
>   'Hashable'

so what that means? and how to solve it?

Well the set is kind of special collection in Swift since it *cannot* has duplicated elements, which leads to ask "how to determine that a dictionary is unique".

As a workaround, you could implement an extension similar to:

```
extension Dictionary: Hashable  {
    public var hashValue: Int {
        return self.keys.map { $0.hashValue }.reduce(0, +)
    }

    public static func ==(lhs: Dictionary<Key, Value>, rhs: Dictionary<Key, Value>) -> Bool {
        return lhs.keys == rhs.keys
    }
}
```

thus you would be able to do:

```
let dic1 = ["key" : "value"]
let dic2 = ["key2" : "value"]
let dic3 = ["key3" : "value"]
let dic4 = ["key2" : "value"]
let dic5 = ["key3" : "value"]

var map = Set<Dictionary<String, String>>()

_ = map.insert(dic1)
_ = map.insert(dic2)
_ = map.insert(dic3)
_ = map.insert(dic4)
_ = map.insert(dic5)

print(map) // [["key2": "value"], ["key": "value"], ["key3": "value"]] (unordered)
```

Note that based on the above implemented extension, you could also declare a set of dictionaries of ints keys and ints values -for example-:

```
var intsMap = Set<Dictionary<Int, Int>>()

var d1 = [1: 12]
var d2 = [2: 101]
var d3 = [1: 1000]

intsMap.insert(d1)
intsMap.insert(d2)
intsMap.insert(d3)

print(intsMap) // [[2: 101], [1: 12]] (unordered)
```